# getting DOcplexException: cannot convert to expression: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f59feda16d0>

Tags: cplex, docplex, operations-research

Im trying this code

m.minimize(30*sum(x["Product A",j])+28*sum(I["Product B",j])+0.9*sum(I["Product A",j])+0.75*sum(I["Product B",j])for i in Products)

and it keeps giving me DOcplexException: cannot convert to expression: <generator object  error

please help me break this down or let it work

Answer (score 0):

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model 
m = Model()
Products=["Product A","Product B"]
Days=[1,2]

I = {}

for i in Products:
    for j in Days:
            I[(i,j)] = m.integer_var()

    
m.add(I[("Product A",1)]==10)

m.minimize(m.sum(30*I[("Product A",j)]+28*I[("Product B",j)]+0.9*I[("Product A",j)]+0.75*I[("Product B",j)] for j in Days))

m.solve()

print("objective = ",m.objective_value)
```

works fine and gives

```
objective =  309.0
```